# add tabs in rdp-plugin/includes/settings.php and get settings saved

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options, tabs

In my plugin settings page i have to add a lot more settings. To get it correct I need some tabs for better understanding.
Here a screenshot as I add it with simple html coding in my `rdp-plugin/includes/settings.php`

[image]

```
<h3 class="nav-tab-wrapper">     
<a class="nav-tab nav-tab-active" href="#">Test1</a>
<a class="nav-tab" href="#">Test2</a>
<a class="nav-tab" href="#">Test3</a>
<a class="nav-tab" href="#">Test4</a>
</h3>
```

But how can I declare some inputs in the tabs 2-6 for editing + saving per tab into table `wp_options`?

tab-1 is main page of settings file. with a `form method="post"` i can save the settings from that part correct.
but how to do this for the remain tabs is not clear for me.

Found a sample plugin for tabs at [plugin-welcome-screen-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA41O.png) but could not get the code from the plugin running in my `settings.php` file. The example plugin does work standalone. But I do not understand how to get it working in my plugin.

Maybe somebody of you can give me a hint getting tabs working as ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody with the same question: i have found a good working solution at [howto_js_tabs.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)